# Wordpress page isn't showing stylesheet

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

My wordpress page isn't showing any stylesheet.

http://www.soenhks.dk/

I did a few changes to the hardcoded menu inside the header.php and then it went like this.

A cookie to the person who finds the flaw.

Answer (score 4):

Check this in your header

```
href="<u?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?>"
```

and remove the u between < and ?

Comment: Thanks you! How did you find the flaw?

Comment: you are welcome. I checked it with firebug in the elements section. Please mark it as resolved / accept the answer :)

Comment: Developer Tools in Chrome are also nice for this kind of investigation

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<u?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?>" />
```

with this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?>" />
```